# custom release on top of upstream release

Tags: git, github

I am trying to understand what is the correct process to follow in git to achieve the following:

There is a open source project `git@github.com:userx/prj1.git`. We want to add some additional functionality on top of it and we want it on a specific release version of the upstream git.

Ex:

Day X:

`git@github.com:userx/prj1.git` has

branches -- `master`, `release`, `branch1`, `branch2`
tags     -- `v1.0`, `v1.1`, `v1.2`, `v2.0`, `v2.1`

I fork the above to my repo at `git@github.com:me/me-prj1.git`.

I add the upstream project using `git remote add upstream git@github.com:userx/prj1.git`.

Day Y:

I checkout tag `v1.2` to put our changes and maintain it separately

`git checkout v1.2`
`git checkout -b me-v1.2` (my branch name corresponding to tag `v1.2` on upstream)

Do changes (including changing the artifact name, as we want to identify it separately from the actual release artifact.)

push to my remote and tag the release as (`me-v1.2`)

Day Z:

I now need to have the changes in the new tag `v2.4` on upstream. How do I achieve this? Are there some good tips to follow that will make it easier?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on where you're getting stuck. Why can't you simply merge like you would with any other project?

Comment: Do you have write access to the upstream repository?

Comment: @Makoto Nope i dont have write access to upstream. I think one way would be get the upstream changes and then create a branch from the tag i want to release on.. followed by merging the me-v1.2 branch on to it.

Comment: Only question i have is, the tags from upstream are fetched locally when i do "git fetch upstream".  how do i push these tags to my remote ? do i have to always do "git push origin --tags" ?

Answer (score 0):

Same as my last comment above, for now looks like the tags have to be pushed explicitly.